# Placing input next to label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3.0.0

How do I place the input next to the label?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="zipID">Zip Code:</label>
      <select name="zipID" id="zipID" class="form-control input-sm" required message="Please select a zip code.">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="34201" class="notranslate">34201</option>
        <option value="34202" class="notranslate">34202</option>
        <option value="34203" class="notranslate">34203</option>
        <option value="34204" class="notranslate">34204</option>
        <option value="34205" class="notranslate">34205</option>
        <option value="34207" class="notranslate">34207</option>
        <option value="34208" class="notranslate">34208</option>
        <option value="34209" class="notranslate">34209</option>
        <option value="34210" class="notranslate">34210</option>
        <option value="34211" class="notranslate">34211</option>
        <option value="34212" class="notranslate">34212</option>
        <option value="34281" class="notranslate">34281</option>
        <option value="34215" class="notranslate">34215</option>
        <option value="34216" class="notranslate">34216</option>
        <option value="34217" class="notranslate">34217</option>
        <option value="34219" class="notranslate">34219</option>
        <option value="34221" class="notranslate">34221</option>
        <option value="34222" class="notranslate">34222</option>
        <option value="34228" class="notranslate">34228</option>
        <option value="34243" class="notranslate">34243</option>
        <option value="34251" class="notranslate">34251</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to place the select drop down right next to the label instead of underneath it. How do I make the input next to the label?

Comment: "I am using bootstrap 3.0.0" — That isn't what your code says.

Comment: `jquery/2.2.4` — jQuery 2.x is unsupported and no longer receives security updates. Use a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: Bootstrap 3.x has some serious bugs, I highly recommend upgrading to the current bootstrap 4.x, it has loads of new reliable components and makes everything easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the elements beside one another use `display:inline-block` (or you could use flex with flex-direction of row if you were using flex-box but that's for another day). You are using Bootstrap css but you can add some css of your own. It is because the css is predefined in bootstrap that I've had to add the `!important` in front of the inline-block attribute.

I have added a class "label-control" to your label. You could add the `form-control` class and size them both the same but then you may want to take the border off the label by adding `label.form-control{border:none;}` if you do this. By creating a new class, you can size the elements differently.

Hope this helps

```css
.label-control {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 30%;
}

.form-control {
  display: inline-block!important;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="zipID" class="label-control">Zip Code:</label>
      <select name="zipID" id="zipID" class="form-control input-sm" required message="Please select a zip code.">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="34201" class="notranslate">34201</option>
        <option value="34202" class="notranslate">34202</option>
        <option value="34203" class="notranslate">34203</option>
        <option value="34204" class="notranslate">34204</option>
        <option value="34205" class="notranslate">34205</option>
        <option value="34207" class="notranslate">34207</option>
        <option value="34208" class="notranslate">34208</option>
        <option value="34209" class="notranslate">34209</option>
        <option value="34210" class="notranslate">34210</option>
        <option value="34211" class="notranslate">34211</option>
        <option value="34212" class="notranslate">34212</option>
        <option value="34281" class="notranslate">34281</option>
        <option value="34215" class="notranslate">34215</option>
        <option value="34216" class="notranslate">34216</option>
        <option value="34217" class="notranslate">34217</option>
        <option value="34219" class="notranslate">34219</option>
        <option value="34221" class="notranslate">34221</option>
        <option value="34222" class="notranslate">34222</option>
        <option value="34228" class="notranslate">34228</option>
        <option value="34243" class="notranslate">34243</option>
        <option value="34251" class="notranslate">34251</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you could alternately split the bootstrap' grid' so that the zip code is one div and the select is in the next..

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most elegant solution but you could use HTML's table function: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

I altered your code to provide what I believe is the desired result, have a great day and good luck with the rest of your form!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <tr>
      <th><label for="zipID">Zip Code:</label></th>
      <th>
      <select name="zipID" id="zipID" class="form-control input-sm" required message="Please select a zip code.">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="34201" class="notranslate">34201</option>
        <option value="34202" class="notranslate">34202</option>
        <option value="34203" class="notranslate">34203</option>
        <option value="34204" class="notranslate">34204</option>
        <option value="34205" class="notranslate">34205</option>
        <option value="34207" class="notranslate">34207</option>
        <option value="34208" class="notranslate">34208</option>
        <option value="34209" class="notranslate">34209</option>
        <option value="34210" class="notranslate">34210</option>
        <option value="34211" class="notranslate">34211</option>
        <option value="34212" class="notranslate">34212</option>
        <option value="34281" class="notranslate">34281</option>
        <option value="34215" class="notranslate">34215</option>
        <option value="34216" class="notranslate">34216</option>
        <option value="34217" class="notranslate">34217</option>
        <option value="34219" class="notranslate">34219</option>
        <option value="34221" class="notranslate">34221</option>
        <option value="34222" class="notranslate">34222</option>
        <option value="34228" class="notranslate">34228</option>
        <option value="34243" class="notranslate">34243</option>
        <option value="34251" class="notranslate">34251</option>
      </select>
      </th>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</table>
</tr>
```

Comment: I was looking for the bootstrap way

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/tables/ here is the bootstrap docs on their tables function check it out, pretty much what I added but with appended classes depending what style your going for

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using CSS. Here is your example working as desired using a few CSS Properties and a parent DIV. This could also be done using bootstrap's grid.

`

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div style="white-space: nowrap">
                        <label style="display: inline-block">Zip Code:</label>
                        <select name="zipID" id="zipID" style="display: inline-block" required
                            message="Please select a zip code.">
                            <option value="">Please Select</option>
                            <option value="34201" class="notranslate">34201</option>
                            <option value="34202" class="notranslate">34202</option>
                            <option value="34203" class="notranslate">34203</option>
                            <option value="34204" class="notranslate">34204</option>
                            <option value="34205" class="notranslate">34205</option>
                            <option value="34207" class="notranslate">34207</option>
                            <option value="34208" class="notranslate">34208</option>
                            <option value="34209" class="notranslate">34209</option>
                            <option value="34210" class="notranslate">34210</option>
                            <option value="34211" class="notranslate">34211</option>
                            <option value="34212" class="notranslate">34212</option>
                            <option value="34281" class="notranslate">34281</option>
                            <option value="34215" class="notranslate">34215</option>
                            <option value="34216" class="notranslate">34216</option>
                            <option value="34217" class="notranslate">34217</option>
                            <option value="34219" class="notranslate">34219</option>
                            <option value="34221" class="notranslate">34221</option>
                            <option value="34222" class="notranslate">34222</option>
                            <option value="34228" class="notranslate">34228</option>
                            <option value="34243" class="notranslate">34243</option>
                            <option value="34251" class="notranslate">34251</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the `form-inline` class to achieve your goal:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
      <div class="form-group form-inline">
        <label for="zipID">Zip Code:</label>
        <select name="zipID" id="zipID" class="form-control input-sm" required message="Please select a zip code.">
                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                <option value="34201" class="notranslate">34201</option>
                <option value="34202" class="notranslate">34202</option>
                <option value="34203" class="notranslate">34203</option>
                <option value="34204" class="notranslate">34204</option>
                <option value="34205" class="notranslate">34205</option>
                <option value="34207" class="notranslate">34207</option>
                <option value="34208" class="notranslate">34208</option>
                <option value="34209" class="notranslate">34209</option>
                <option value="34210" class="notranslate">34210</option>
                <option value="34211" class="notranslate">34211</option>
                <option value="34212" class="notranslate">34212</option>
                <option value="34281" class="notranslate">34281</option>
                <option value="34215" class="notranslate">34215</option>
                <option value="34216" class="notranslate">34216</option>
                <option value="34217" class="notranslate">34217</option>
                <option value="34219" class="notranslate">34219</option>
                <option value="34221" class="notranslate">34221</option>
                <option value="34222" class="notranslate">34222</option>
                <option value="34228" class="notranslate">34228</option>
                <option value="34243" class="notranslate">34243</option>
                <option value="34251" class="notranslate">34251</option>
              </select>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Refer [Inline Form](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline) for futher clarification. Or maybe what you trying to do is actually [Horizontal Form](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-horizontal).